# Initializing Custom UITableViewCell with parameters

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, initialization

I am trying to create an array of UITableViewCells and before I append the cells I need to initialize them with parameters. When I try to initialize the cell I get an error that the two properties in the class were never defined. But after I defined them I get an error that the variables were used before being initialized. Here is the class

```
class SimpleCellClassTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var artist: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var picture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var songTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var sender: UILabel!
var audioFile: AnyObject? = nil
var mediaType: songType! = nil
var id: NSNumber! = nil

 override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


func configureCell(Title title: NSString?,
                         File audioFile: AnyObject?,
                         Type mediaType: songType,
                          Artist artist: NSString?,
                            Image image: UIImage?,
                          Sender sender: NSString?,
                                  ID id: NSNumber?) -> UITableViewCell {

    self.audioFile = audioFile
    self.mediaType = mediaType

    if let newSender = sender{
        self.sender.text = newSender as String
    }

    if let newTitle = title{
        self.songTitle.text = newTitle as String

    }

    if let newImage = image {
        self.picture.image = newImage
    }

    if let newArtist = artist {
        self.artist.text = newArtist as String
    }

    if let newId = id {
        self.id = newId as NSNumber

    }

    return self
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
```

And this is where Im trying to initialize and then add values to it with configure cell method:

```
let newSongCell = SimpleCellClassTableViewCell.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "SimpleCell") 

        newSongCell.configureCell(Title: setTitle,
                                   File: setAudioFile,
                                   Type: setMediaType,
                                 Artist: setArtist,
                                  Image: setImage,
                                 Sender: setSender,
                                     ID: setId)
```

The parameters for File and Type are the ones throwing the same error. Also if I need to use the initializer with NSCoder what should I put as the argument?

Comment: var mediaType: songType! = nil

//Check this line of code.. change to 
var mediaType: songType? = nil

Answer (score 1):

I don't see if `audioFile` and `mediaType` properties are defined wrong. There should be no error with them. If you use .xib file - usually you should not use explicit initializer. And for sure you must not do this in your case, because you trying to use outlets. When you use `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` you miss your .xib file and all UI. Assume that .xib filename is *SimpleCellClassTableViewCell.xib*, Custom Class for UITableViewCell in Identity Inspector is set to `SimpleCellClassTableViewCell`, reuse identifier is set to "SimpleCell". I offer you use this code for initializing your cell:

```
guard let newSongCell = UINib(nibName: "SimpleCellClassTableViewCell", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil).first as? SimpleCellClassTableViewCell
else
{
    fatalError("Error loading SimpleCellClassTableViewCell")
}
```

Usually you should not use initializer with NSCoder explicitly. This initializer used by storyboard or .nib file.

At last, if you use outlets from storyboard - then you shouldn't try to get cell instance by any initializer at all. You should use `UITableView`'s `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(forIndexPath:)` method.

That was all about your direct question, **but** in fact you rarely need to initialize `UITableViewCell` by yourself. If you do, probably you do something wrong. Assume again, that you use .xib file, then in most cases you simply register your file in `viewDidLoad` of your table view controller

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SimpleCellClassTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SimpleCell")
```

and then your `tableView` will initialize or reuse `SimpleCellClassTableViewCell` instances for you by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(forIndexPath:)` method

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code. I suggest you to look some examples where `UITableView`. Apple docs or github are good sources for this.

**Issue #1**

You do not need to override designated `UITableViewCell's initializers (below) because you do nothing in the override.

```
public init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

**Issue #2**

Your code does **not** reuse the cell object which is bad.

**Issue #3**

In Swift `init` is not used on the call site, so your cell's initialization code (considering also issue #2) should be

```
var simpleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SimpleCell")
if simpleCell == nil {
    let cell: SimpleCellClassTableViewCell = SimpleCellClassTableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "SimpleCell")
    cell.configureCell(Title: "test",
                        File: "",
                        Type: 2,
                      Artist: "test",
                       Image: UIImage(),
                      Sender: "test",
                          ID: 2)
    simpleCell = cell
}
return simpleCell!
```

**Issue #4**

Do not name function parameters with capitalised first letter (`Title`, `File`, etcetera). This might be confused with a type. Instead, use `title`, `file`, etc.. Again, there are a lot of examples out there.

Try to fix this issues. This *might* help.